# Plone 4 : CalendarWidget to display Year only without Date and Month

Tags: plone

In Plone 4, I am using the CalendarWidget. Is it possible to display only the year in a custom view for a datetime field? Some records that I need to input do not have the month and date but the year has been provided.

Is there a way to limit the widget to allow only the year but ignore the date and month fields unless they are provided?

Currently my code is as follows:

```
atapi.DateTimeField('item_publication_date',
        required=True,
        searchable = True,
        validators = ('isValidDate'),
        widget = atapi.CalendarWidget(
            show_hm=False,
            label=_(u'Publication Date'),
            starting_year=1970,
            format='%Y',
            description=_(u"Item Publication Date"),
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. In Zope, DateTime objects must have a month and day to work at all, and what would they be set to if you only supply a year?

You can, however, use a simple StringField with a dynamic vocabulary to let users pick a year from a drop-down list, then use a custom method on your content class to return a DateTime object for getItem_publication_date() where you take the year for the return value from that field.